# How Do I Use ODBC in CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, cakephp, odbc, cakephp-2.0

I've looked all over the web and cannot seem to find an answer for this one: I'm hoping to develop an app for my company using CakePHP 2. the problem is that the app will have to pull data from a Progress OpenEdge database. I've got the ODBC SQL driver for the database installed on the server but I cannot figure out how to add an ODBC datasource in CakePHP 2. Is this supported? If not (pretty stupid in my opinion, seeing as it was supported in 1.3), than what PHP framework would recommend that does support ODBC?

NOTE: While the ODBC driver can communicate SQL commands, you cannot communicate directly with the database using SQL, so it needs to be through the ODBC connection.

Comment: There is an ODBC datasource in CakePHP's datasources project: https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.3/Model/Datasource/Database

Comment: The readme indicates that this plugin is not yet compatible with Cake 2.0 :(

Comment: Yes, though it is also possible that the readme is outdated. It was last updated nine months ago whereas the code was last updated three months ago.

Comment: Good Point, I'll try it out and let you know how it goes